# Validation problem with JSP and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, validation, jsp

I have this simple JSP page in Eclipse and the first line in the file is:

> 

Eclipse however, puts a yellow warning icon before this line with the following tooltip message:

> Multiple annotations found at this
>   line:
>   - Line breakpoint:index.jsp [line: 1]
>   - Tag (jsp:directive.page) should be an empty-element tag.

Does anyone know why this is?

**UPDATE**:

This is my full source script. This is basically the template that Eclipse generates for me when I create a new JSP file based on the XHTML template. I only slightly modified the content to make it do something 'use full'.

I'm using Eclipse 3.4 (eclipse-jee-ganymede-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz) on Ubuntu 8.10 with the Geronimo 2.1 plug-in (I don't think that matters though). I had this same problem with every version of Eclipse I've used so far (3.0 and up)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<jsp:useBean id="datetime" class="java.util.Date" />
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello Geronimo</title>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Hello Apache Geronimo!!!</h1>on ${datetime}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right, but does a DOCTYPE with XHTML 4.01 is enough to make that warning disappear ?

Comment: Yes. it makes the warning go away. However, I didn't know there was such thing as XHTML 4.01... I've also upgraded to the latest version of Eclipse. That also did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an oddity of the DOM validation that happens in the editor even for JSP files, reported in [**bug 248963**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=248963) for another situation.
It's expected to be resolved in WTP 3.0.4 & Ganymede SR2.

So what eclipse and WTP version are you using ?

Can you check if this is still the case when you add the following line just beneath the initial jsp declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

as mentioned in [**bug 257258**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=257258) (also fixed in WTP 3.0.4 & Ganymede SR2): before WTP3.0.4, this doctype was enough to *not show* your warning:

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipsetotale.com](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/img/art7-editeurJSP.png))</sub>

Comment: I've updated my question with more info. Thanks for your response.

Comment: By the way, your DOCTYPE solves the problem but I do not use Transitional (X)HTML. Ever :)

Comment: All right! But that means a more recent eclipse3.4 should be able to fix this (not forcing you the change the DOCTYPE)